# How to link a C object file with a Assembly Language object file?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, ld, gnu-assembler

I am having trouble linking 2 object files one of which was generated from an Assembly Language Source File and another that was generated from a C Source file.

C source code:

```
//main2.c
extern int strlength(char *);
int main(){
    char * test = "hello";
    int num = strlength(test);
    return num;
}
```

Assembly source code:

```
#strlength.s
.include "Linux32.s"

.section .text
.globl strlength
.type strlength, @function
strlength:
 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp, %ebp
 movl $0, %ecx
 movl 8(%ebp), %edx
read_next_byte:
 movb (%edx), %al
 cmpb $END_OF_FILE, %al
 jle end
 incl %edx
 incl %ecx
 jmp read_next_byte
end:
 movl %ecx, %eax
 popl %ebp
 ret
```

When I compile and run using 'gcc' like this:

```
gcc main2.c strlength.s -m32 -o test
./test
echo $?
```

I get 5 which is correct. However when I compile/assemble separately and then link with 'ld'
like this:

```
as strlength.s --32 -o strlength.o
cc main2.c -m32 -o main2.o
ld -melf_i386 -e main main2.o strlength.o -o test
./test
```

I get a segmentation fault. What is causing this? Am I not following the C calling convention 100% correctly?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> `ld -melf_i386 -e main main2.o strlength.o -o test`

Don't do that. Do this instead:

```
gcc -m32 main2.o strlength.o -o test
```

(You should probably not call your test exectuable `test`, as it may conflict with the `/bin/test`, standard on most UNIX systems.)

Explanation: UNIX binaries do *not* generally start executing at `main`. They start executing in a function called `_start`, which comes from `crt1.o` or similar ("C Runtime startup"). *That* file is part of libc, and it arranges for various initializations, required for the proper start up of your application.

Your program actually doesn't require *anything* from `libc`, which is why you were able to link it with `ld`.

However, consider what happens after your `main` returns. *Normally*, the code in `crt1.o` will execute (equivalent of) `exit(main(argc, argv));`. Since you linked without `crt1.o`, there is nobody to do that final `exit` for you, so the code returns to ... undefined location and promptly crashes.

Answer (score 4):

You also need to link the `crt1.o` (might have a different name, contains the necessary code up until `main` can be called) and necessary libraries. GCC also usually needs to link to `libgcc.so` which contains necessary helper functions (for example, when doing 64 bit calculations on a 32 bit system) plus other system libraries. For example, on my Mac, it also needs to link to `libSystem` which also contain the usual C functions like `printf`. On Linux, that's usually `libc`.

Note that your program cannot directly start with `main` (as you're trying to do with with `ld .. -e main`), the entry point needs to set up a few things prior to calling the C function `main`. That's what the previously mentioned `crt1.o` is doing. I guess the segmentation fault is a result of this missing setup.

To see what GCC is exactly doing *on your system*, call:

```
gcc main2.c strlength.s -m32 -o test -v
```