# What is the correct way to link assembly code with C code using gcc

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Suppose you have the following assembly files:

```
  .file "print.s"
  .intel_syntax noprefix

  .text

  .globl _start
  .type _start, @function
_start:
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  lea rsi, hello_string
  mov rdx, 14
  syscall
  mov rax, 60
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
  .size _start, .-_start
```

and

```
  .file "string.s"
  .intel_syntax noprefix

  .data

  .globl hello_string
  .type hello_string, @object
hello_string:
  .string "Hello, world!\n"
  .size hello_string, 14
```

If you run `as string.s -o string.o`, `as print.s -o print.o` and then `ld *.o -o hello.elf`, you get a executable file which prints Hello, world!. Now suppose that you change the `_start` label in print.s to `print` and you have the following C file:

```
// main.c
void print(void);

int main (void) {
  print();
  return 0;
}
```

I want to run something like `gcc -o main.elf main.c string.s print.s` to take my two assembly files and link them into the standard C runtime. This command as written doesn't work. I get the following error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccc1yRif.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `hello_string' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I can't figure out how to correctly use the -fPIC flag to make things work. I am not even sure if that is what I should be doing. I could try and use the inline assembler to do this, but for my actual use cases, that would be extremely annoying and I would much rather learn how to correctly link assembly chunks into my C programs. I haven't been able to find much information about this online.

> **Question:**  How do you correctly use the GNU linker to link assembly files into the C runtime?

EDIT: In [How to link a C object file with a Assembly Language object file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691138/how-to-link-a-c-object-file-with-a-assembly-language-object-file), the OP is asking about how to solve a similar linking problem just using `ld`. I want to use `gcc` which is the recommended solution in the linked question, but I can't even get that to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link a C object file with a Assembly Language object file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691138/how-to-link-a-c-object-file-with-a-assembly-language-object-file)

Comment: @RobinGreen: Hi Robin, that question is a little different. The OP is asking about how do this linking just using `ld`. I want to use `gcc`, which is their recommended answer, but it isn't working for me and I don't understand why

Comment: But you are not calling it the same way as in the recommended answer. Obviously you can leave off the `-m32` because you are writing 64-bit code, but it looks like you should output a `.o` not a `.elf`.

Comment: I get what you are saying. Maybe I should be producing an object file from my c file first and then combining the three object files together with gcc. However, when I try and compile exactly the OPs C file `main2.c` using `gcc main2.c -o main2.o`, the linker errors out and complains about an undefined reference to `strlength`

Comment: @RobinGreen: Do you know how to make gcc output a relocatable object file? I cant see the flag for it in the manual. The -o outputs an elf file which can be directly loaded by the opsys. This isn't relocatable so cant be linked anymore

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I have figured it out now. The error message seems to be telling me that  gcc is trying to make a shared object. This lead me to the question [gcc 6.2.0 is attempting to create shared object when it shouldn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40246054/gcc-6-2-0-is-attempting-to-create-shared-object-when-it-shouldnt)

The solution is to run `gcc -no-pie main.c string.s print.s -o main.elf`

according to the man page, `-no-pie` tells gcc to not produce a position indipendent executable.

Comment: A better solution is to write C code that defines and refers to a string (e.g., a small function that returns the address of the string), compile it to assembly, examine the assembly to see how the compiler refers to the string in a position-independent way, then use that technique in your own code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yeah that is a good idea! Thanks for the thought